# Why isn't Python itertools.combinations() in O(1) amortized time complexity?

Tags: python, time-complexity, combinations, python-itertools, amortized-analysis

The [itertools.combinations function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2676-L2690) of the CPython's standard library doesn't have an $O(1)$ amortized time complexity. When generating $k$-combinations of $n$ elements, the main issue arises from when $k$ gets close to $n$. We end up with an $O(n)$ amortized time complexity.

1. Why such a choice from Python core developers ?
2. Does there exist a code, whether it be a from a standard library or not, that guarantees an O(1) amortized time complexity ?

Quick details of why i ended up with amortized time complexity of $O(n)$ :
In that code, the number of combinations ensuring the pivot index is $i$ is $\binom{n-k+i}{i+1}$ and the number of array operations for such an instance is $3k-3i-1$. By multipliying both quantities and summing over all possible values of $i$, we obtain the total number of operations. Dividing this by $\binom{n}{k}$ the number of combinations, we end up with the amortized time complexity of $O(n)$.

The following self-contained C code is a rewrite of the CPython itertools.combinations function made for handling k-combinations of an array of integers between 0 and n-1, in an iterator-type style.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <stdbool.h> //bool, true, false

/* TESTING */
int* integersInOrder(int size){
    int* array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = i;
    return array;
}

void printArray(int* array, int size){
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d ", (int)array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

/* itertools.combinations */
static const bool IS_RUNNING = true, IS_DONE = false;

bool nextCombination(int* indices, int n, int k){
    if(k > n)
        return IS_DONE;
    
    bool isFound = false;
    int i;
    // find furthest-right non-maximal index
    for(i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(indices[i] != n - k + i){
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isFound)
        return IS_DONE;
    
    // increase index i by 1
    indices[i]++;
    // set all indices to the right of i to be the lexicographical minimum values
    for(int j = i + 1; j < k; j++)
        indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
   
    return IS_RUNNING;
}

/* ENTRY POINT */
int main()
{
    int n = 5, k = 3;
    int* array = integersInOrder(k);
    printArray(array, k);
    
    while(IS_RUNNING == nextCombination(array, n, k)){
        printArray(array, k);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You gotta build the tuple, and that's going to take more than O(1) time on its own.

Comment: FYI you can't use MathJax in SO markdown (I assume that's what the `$n$` stuff is).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that you modify `array` in place. If CPython were to adapt your implementation, the result of `list(itertools.combinations(range(4), 3))` would be something like `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`, which would be surprising to users. You would need to make a copy of the first k entries in `array` and yield that, which will take O(k) at the minimum, which, as k approaches n, is O(n).

You can't escape these copies without breaking user's expectations.

Comment: Well, yes, but the array in question is only created once, rather than choose(n, k) times, which is what @UnderscorePoY was concerned about.

Comment: I understand the fact that the library doesn't want in-place modification of one tuple. Nevertheless, creating the tuple or not, the remaining code is still O(n) amortized. So, why not go for an O(1) amortized solution for tracking what is the next combination of indices, and let the complexity reach O(n) or O(k) from creating the tuple ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is in that case. You understand these tuples of size O(n) will have to be created anyway, so I'm not sure why an asymptotic complexity of O(1 + n) = O(n) would be preferable to one of O(n + n) = O(n). Is there something I'm missing about your question?

Comment: I do understand that O(1+n) = O(n) = O(n+n). My question is why going for an O(n+n) implementation, instead of an O(1+n) implementation, when the previous has a decent chance to have a worse total execution time ?

Comment: Second idea could be : if the indices matched the content to produce the iterations from, one could go O(1) amortized time complexity, but the itertools code would produce O(n), which seems worse.